# Store Date in Oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, date

I have a POJO named Employee.Java who has an instance variable, lets call it birthdate. I have it's type mentioned as java.util.Date and it's corresponding column type in Oracle table is DATE.

```
Employee.Java

Class Employee{
 private java.util.Date birthDate;
}


Table
create table Employee(birthDate DATE);
```

I have another class which takes an instance of Employee class and saves it to database. Since the type of birthdate column is DATE, it will be stored in the default format DD-MON-YY in table.

I need to store the birthDate value in database in the format YYYY-MM-DD with java.util.Date typed instance variable. How can I achieve this task. Kindly assist me.

Answer (score 4):

The date in database has no specific format. You shouldn't interfere with how Oracle stores the date. However, you can use PLSQL's **to_date** and **to_char** functions to format the value if you want to read the data back in a specific format.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However my question is I need to save my date in Oracle table in the format YYYY-MM-DD with Oracle Table's datatype set as Date. Is it possible. DONOT want to change the format while retrieving, I just need to know if inserting in that format is possible with type set as DATE.

Comment: @Rushabh: as amir has explained: a `date` does ***not*** have any format. The format you see is applied by the client application when *displaying* a date. You don't "store a date in a format", you just "store a date"

Comment: To emphasize the point… *storing* data and *displaying* data are two different tasks. Most databases store date-time data types as binary or numbers, almost never as a text-related type. When displaying the data retrieved from a query, some kind of formatting must be applied to *create* and deliver a text string that represents the stored date-time value.